# JBoss 7 and oracle 10g : "wrong driver class" using ojdbc14.jar

Tags: oracle, driver, jboss7.x

I'm trying to configure a data-source on jboss 7.1 with oracle 10g but I have the following errors :

```
16:23:24,155 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (MSC service thread 1-4) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
        ...
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Wrong driver class [class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] for this connection URL [jdbc:inetora:...:...:...?timestampToDate=true&streamstolob=true]
```

My configuration in standalone.xml is :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url><![CDATA[jdbc:inetora:...:...:...?timestampToDate=true&streamstolob=true]]></connection-url>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user_name</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
        <timeout>
            <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
        <validation>
            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
        </validation>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc14">
            <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
    </datasources> 
</subsystem>
```

My persistence.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
   version="1.0">   
   <persistence-unit name="defaultEntityManager" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>java:/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>   
</persistence>
```

In JBoss modules/, I added a com/oracle/ojdbc14/main directory containing ojdbc14.jar and a module.xml file :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbc14">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc14.jar"/>
  </resources>
   <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

Any idea of how I could resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

your connection url is incorrect in standalone xml.

it is:

```
 <connection-url><![CDATA[jdbc:inetora:...:...:... timestampToDate=true&streamstolob=true]]></connection-url>
```

however it should be:

```
 <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/myservicename
```

Comment: spent a whole day trying to figure this out! thanks a lot!